# Example of Sidecar Application for Microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, microservices

Is Spring cloud config server an example of sidecar application for microservices?

Comment: Could you explain what you understand as sidecar application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean if the Spring Cloud Config Server itself is what the Spring Cloud documentation labels as Sidecar? Then no, as far as I know it is just a plain, regular Spring Boot app.

A Sidecar as referred to in [Polyglot support with Sidecar](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_polyglot_support_with_sidecar) is a Spring Boot application that acts as a bridge between your service infrastructure and a service that is not written in a JVM language. Apps written in Python, Go, Ruby, C#, NodeJS, Erlang or really any other language that can bind *something* to a port come to mind.

The benefits of the Sidecar are, that your Non-JVM apps

- `service discovery` become automatically discoverable through [Eureka](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_service_discovery_eureka_clients), which means that JVM services can resolve the `host:port/<service-id>` of the Non-JVM apps as well as the other way around,
- `monitoring` are *monitorable* through the same health-endpoints-infrastructure that is available in Spring Boot (Actuator), i.e. by manually providing the health endpoint in the Non-JVM app Eureka knows when the Non-JVM service is down
- `routing/proxying` query the services by either manually looking up their hosts/ports or proxying these requests through [Zuul](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_router_and_filter_zuul), which in turn resolves their current addresses through Eureka
- `balancing` be load balanced by [Ribbon](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-ribbon) and
- `configuration` may consume configuration properties provided via [Spring Cloud Config](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_spring_cloud_config).

> I hope this answer addresses your question, if not (or someone finds it to be inaccurate or misleading) just let me know and I delete it to make room for something more suitable. ;-)

Comment: So sidecar is primary to support a non-jvm app to run along with a app running on jvm?